# Spring boot JPA Unknown User

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I want to integrate Spring and JPA I'm using spring boot. First I tried to create SessionFactory using EntityManager, but I can't. I've already asked this question here [Spring boot inject EntityManagerFactory in configuration class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643702/spring-boot-inject-entitymanagerfactory-in-configuration-class). Those pieces of advice didn't help me and It still doesn't work. So now I decided to try to persist by entityManager, but when I persist my object I get an error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: kz.training.springrest.entity.User
```

There is my User class

```
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_id_seq_gen", sequenceName = "user_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_id_seq_gen")
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String username;
    @Column
    private String password;
}
```

Service class

```
package kz.training.springrest.service;

import kz.training.springrest.entity.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void insertUser(User user) {
        entityManager.persist(user);
    }

}
```

Runner

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="kz.training.springrest")
public class SpringrestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringrestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Database configuration just in case) there is nothing yet

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement

public class DatabaseConfiguration {

}
```

My dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ring
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.show-sql = false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true


#Note: The last two properties on the code snippet above were added to suppress an annoying exception
# that occurs when JPA (Hibernate) tries to verify PostgreSQL CLOB feature.
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share complete exception stacktrace by editing your qs and pasting the stacktrace. Also you have not set `spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver` in your `application.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Add `@EntityScan` for your `SpringrestApplication`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="kz.training.springrest")
@EntityScan("kz.training.springrest.entity")
public class SpringrestApplication {
```

Comment: Greaat) Thank you a lot)